# Powershell - Line break in 'Notes' field of an AD object

Tags: powershell, active-directory, line-breaks

I've set up a script for automatic user creation in our AD.
Everything is working beautifully, except for one thing. The *Notes* field in the index tab *Telephones* of an AD object seems to ignore any line breaks added in Powershell.

```
$notes = "E-Mail: $mail`nPhone: $phone`nInternal Contact:$contact"

#random irrelevant code in between

OtherAttributes   = @{
        'info' = $notes
}
```

OtherAttributes is part of a hashtable with other AD user parameters as well.

Screenshots of 1) how it is and 2) how it should be.

[image: How it is]

[image]

Is this even possible?

It doesn't have any issues when doing it manually, so I'm assuming there has to be a way for it to work via script.

Comment: Try with ```"E-Mail: $mail`r`nPhone: $phone`r`nInternal Contact:$contact"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create the notes in a single double-quoted line, then use Windows newlines (CRLF) like [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867802/powershell-line-break-in-notes-field-of-an-ad-object#comment133822646_75867802) already commented:

```
$notes = "E-Mail: $mail`r`nPhone: $phone`r`nInternal Contact: $contact"
```

or fill these in with the [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f):

```
$notes = "E-Mail: $mail{0}Phone: $phone{0}Internal Contact: $contact" -f [Environment]::NewLine
```

Perhaps an even better approach would be to use a Here-String:

```
$notes = @"
E-Mail: $mail
Phone: $phone
Internal Contact: $contact
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, but it what I used.

I created a variable named $nls and just put a return there to use in my concatenated strings. It made things easier to read.

$nls = "
"

Comment: Thats what ``r` is for the previous answer.